# Как сделать, чтобы после удаления элементов из списка, мгновенно появлялся текст List work is empty, без обновления страницы

Tags: css

Есть список  и кнопка `Clear all`, при нажатии на которую происходит удаление всех элементов из списка - начинает работать `js` код(который и осуществляет удаление всех элементов). Но для того чтобы увидеть пустой список, мне нужно сделать `refresh` страницы. Как сделать так, чтобы после удаления всех элементов, мгновенно - (без обновления страницы) появлялась запись, например(`list work is empty`). Можно ли реализовать это с помощью `css`?

```html
<button id="clear_all">Clear all</button>    
<div id="list">
        <ul id="include">
          <li>Task</li>
          <li>Task</li>
          <li>Task</li>
        </ul>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul:empty:before {
  content: "Пустой список";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kknhu4sv/
https://jsfiddle.net/5zshf309/
Но заметьте, что в ul не должно быть ни пробелов, ни табов и вообще ни каких символов.

Comment: спасибо за помощь! помогло)